# How to find out which O356 Dynamic emails groups a user is a member of?

Tags: powershell, email, dynamic, exchange-server

There appear to many pages on the web detailing how to enumerate the members of a dynamic email group using powershell, but I can't find out how you find which dynamic groups a specific user is in. Surely this is a quite basic requirement?

I'm looking for the dynamic group equivalent of
`Get-DistributionGroup -Filter "Members -eq ""CN=xxxxx xxxxxx,OU=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=local"""`

I realise that Dynamic groups are dynamic, but surely there must be a way to replicate what exchange does when an email is sent to the group?
Helpfully get-help Get-DistributionGroup does not exist...

Edit: from mulling it over overnight and people's reponses, it would seem it needs to be a multi stage process.

Create list of dynamic distribution groups
Create list of members for first group
Search for specific user within list and report yes or no
Repeat for next group etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a place where developers post the code they are trying to make work. Please copy and paste the code you are trying to make work into the question. Or, ask on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Well, you can write a script that just enumerates through all dynamic distributiongroups and checks which ones match your user. The code for this is trivial to write, even for a Powershell beginner. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/dynamic-distribution-groups/view-dynamic-distribution-group-members?view=exchserver-2016 for information explaining how to get the members of dynamic distributiongroups.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Dynamic groups are dynamic and Dynamic assignment of group members is automatically calculated based on the filters and criteria that you set.

So you need to queries whether some of the User's properties match the set condition i.e. SMTP if you want to get the dynamic group by a specific user.(As I understand) Right?

However, I have not found such a mapping relationship. But there is a simple work-around which enumerates all dynamic distributiongroups and checks which ones match your user.

In fact, you can use UserName/Address and other property to match it. Of course, I know this is not the best solution.